# Filling combobox with range and remove blanks

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I thought this would be simple but for whatever reason, my combobox is always empty and I don't know why! In column B I have text from cell B3 downwards and want this list to populate my combobox (called ComboBox1). Some cells in column B are empty and I do not want these in the combobox so this is the code I have:

```
Private Sub CompanyList()
Dim c As Range
With Worksheets("Database")
    For Each c In Worksheets("Database").Range("B3", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If c.Value <> "" Then ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```

My sheet is called Database, the ActiveX combobox is on the same sheet and it's called ComboBox1. Where am I going wrong here?

UPDATE

I've changed the code so that it runs whenever I update a cell so

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

However, now when I update a cell, it will add the whole of column B in to the combobox again. It's not adding blank cells and it's adding values from underneath blank cells which is good, but it's just adding everything twice over whenever I make a change.

Although thinking about it, I'm not sure why I thought otherwise. However, if I change a company name in the list, I still need the combobox to update in livetime.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the line with `If` to see if you enter it?

Comment: if I set a breakpoint on the If line, then run through the code, it will keep adding the values until an empty cell and then repeatedly add those values... so I'm getting value 1, value 2, value 3, value 1, value 2, value 3 etc. instead of value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few corrections around the `With` statements, to properly define the range :

```
Private Sub CompanyList()
Dim c As Range
ComboBox1.Clear
With Worksheets("Database")
    For Each c In .Range(.Range("B3"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's still not populating the list though. I'm not getting any errors or anything, it just isn't populating the combobox.

Comment: When running the code, it's now populating the combobox up until an empty cell, however, I still have values under the empty cells that need to populate the box. It's not updating live though.

Comment: Strange that it stop after an empty cell... It shouldn't have any issue as you use the `AddItem` method... I'll take a look around to see if there is an explanation!

Comment: @Rory : I guess that is a question for the OP, you should have poked him, I'm not sure he will have the notification for each comment on the answer (I haven't ask much in quite some times, so I'm not sure)

Comment: @SamWells I added the line to empty the combobox before filling it again, let me know if that solve your issue! ;)

Comment: Thank you! That works as a solution. One thing, this only loads when I change a value in column B (after that it works fine), is there a way to get this to load on Workbook_Open but also update when column B is changed? Also, a little off-topic, but is there a way to sort of the combobox alphabetically? As far as I'm aware, VBA cannot sort data can it?

Comment: Yup, just add the name of the sub (`CompanyList`) in the Open event also and it'll be executed everytime you open the workbook! ;)

Comment: @R3uK I have the code in the Worksheet_Change sub, however, the code Private Sub Workbook_Open() Call Worksheet_Change End Sub doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, like I said, you should add *Call CompanyList* in the Open event. so you need to create a real Sub, I you haven't already! ;) You can't call an event handler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96786/discussion-between-sam-wells-and-r3uk).